# Clang 3.0 C++ std::map<>::iterator compilation error

Tags: c++, templates, clang

I have this code:

```
template<typename T>
T* Factory<T>::GetObject(const char* type)
{
    StringID typeID(type);
    map<StringID, T* (*)()>::iterator it = m_createFunctions.find(typeID);
    return it->second();
}
```

It compiles fine on Visual Studio 2010 and 2008, but it doesn't compile on Clang 3.0 (Xcode). I think it compiled fine on GCC, but I'm not sure if it was in the same form as now. The error "; expected after expression" is on this line:

```
map<StringID, T* (*)()>::iterator it = m_createFunctions.find(typeID);
```

Do you know why?

Comment: LLVM? Do you mean Clang?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VC++ accepts your code erroneously — a conformant compiler *should* give you an error here.

`map<StringID, T* (*)()>` uses `T`, which is a dependent type; consequently, to access types inside of `map<StringID, T* (*)()>` such as `iterator`, you need to use the `typename` keyword to disambiguate things for the compiler:

```
typename map<StringID, T* (*)()>::iterator it = m_createFunctions.find(typeID);
```

See this FAQ for further explanation: [What is the template `typename` keyword used for?](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#typename)

---

Note that if you're compiling in C++11 mode, you can use the following simplification instead:

```
auto it = m_createFunctions.find(typeID);
```

Comment: I don't want to use auto for compatibility. Thanks for the answer, it works

Comment: Honestly that's a horrible type to type (sorry) more than once anyway.  Why not just typedef the `map<...>` in your class and use that?

Comment: @Useless : The FAQ I linked proposes exactly that. :-]

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely will have errors in GCC also. 'Typename' is necessary in such cases.